# get matching result from preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Is there an function in PHP that does this:

```
preg_match('/abc [0-9][0-9] xoxo/', $html);
```

and then output the information what is [0-9][0-9]

Example:

string:

```
hi i am string 69 cool!
```

regex:

```
/hi i am string [0-9][0-9] cool!/
```

Output:

```
69
```

Comment: Add a capturing group `()`.

Comment: Your 'string' and 'Output' are identical? Is that really what you intend?

Comment: Sorry, the output should be 69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) returns just a boolean if the whole expression matched. To receive the desired content, you need to supply the third parameter:

```
if (preg_match('/abc (\d+) xoxo/', $html, $matches)) {
#                     / 
#                   / 
    print $matches[1];

}
```

`$matches` will contain the complete matched strings, and any partial results from `(..)` capture groups; here in index `[1]` for your found decimals.

See the manual for more examples.

Comment: Yes, we have enough duplicates. But I can't really uncover such trivial ones.

Answer (score -1):

Pass a `$matches` array to `preg_replace`. It would populate with all the matches.

**[`preg_replace` Manual Entry](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**